# Geth gas limit decreases over time in private PoA network

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, gas-limit, out-of-gas

I have deployed a PoA network with geth, setting gaslimit to 0x1fffffffffffffff in genesis file. When starting mining and over the time, I have realized gaslimit in each new block decreases. I have tried with --targetgaslimit flag as this question suggests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947751/gaslimit-decrease-over-time
However, this flag is not supported for newer versions in geth. Is there any other way to prevent gas limit from decreasing when minning new blocks?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer version the correct parameter is

> --miner.gaslimit value              Target gas ceiling for mined blocks (default: 30000000)

See [geth's commandline help](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options) for other parameters.